# Community Edition 1.9 Order Fullfillment

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, shipping

The inventory on the `Magento` site will be held in a warehouse for a third party who will ship the order.  Is there a way to configure Magento CE make the orders automated so when one is placed the third-party receives this order by email or by sending data to their web service?

Right now when an order is placed by a user, you have to look into the admin site and get the order details and forward to the fulfillment warehouse manually.

Answer (score 1):

If email meets your requirement, you can simply add the vendors email to the list of people that should receive order emails.

```
Configuration>sales>sales emails>Order>Send Order Email Copy To
```

For their web service, you could hook into the Magento API if you have a developer on hand.